# Sytax error while debugging the npm code with PingID

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm-start

I have integrated Ping ID code with Node JS application.Now,While running the npm start to start the server I am getting the error **"Couldn't get an access token. Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc."**

I tried debugging the code I am getting the following syntax error:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=46448 react-auth-client\src\sdk\api.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:46448/754e8497-9f97-47b7-8c65-ddc399231a97
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnec:\pingone-customers-sample-custom-signon-master\react-auth-

```
client\src\sdk\api.js:4
import _ from "lodash";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
ct...
```

Could you please help me on this please?

Comment: this could help you..
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9395

Comment: Thanks for your response Mohan but the above solution didn't worked out for me as I don't have jest.config.js file in my source code.Could you please help me with any other inputs please?